# Accessing MxM numpy array that is first index of a tuple

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tuples

As stated in the title, I have a list of tuples that look like (numpy_array,id) where the numpy array is m x m. I need to access each element of the numpy array (i.e. all  m^2 of them) but am having a tough time doing this without unpacking the tuple.

I would rather not unpack the tuple because of how much data it is/how long that would take due to the amount of data.

If I unpack the tuple the code would look like below, is there a way to index this so that I don't need to unpack?

```
    for x in range(length):
        for y in range(length):
            if(instance1[x][y]==instance2[x][y]):
                distance -=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access directly to a element in a specific position of the ndimensional numpy array, you can just use a **ndimensional indexing**.

For example:
I want to access the element in the third column of the first row  of a 3x3 array *c*, then I will do *c[0,2]*.

```
c = np.random.rand( 3,3 )
print(c)
print( 'Element:', c[0,2])
```

Check the official doc [Numpy Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

_Update__
In case of a list of tuples you should index for each data structure

```
import numpy as np    
a =[ 
        ( np.random.rand( 2,2 ), 0 ), #first  tuple
        ( np.random.rand( 2,2 ), 2 ), #second  tuple
        ( np.random.rand( 2,2 ), 3 ), # ...
        ( np.random.rand( 2,2 ), 1 )
        ]

    print( np.shape(a) )    # accessing list a
    # (4,2)
    print( np.shape(a[0]) ) # accessing the first tuple in a
    # (2)
    print( np.shape(a[0][0]) ) # accessing the 2x2 array inside the first tuple
    # (2,2)
    print( np.shape(a[0][0][0,1]) ) # accessing the [0,1] element inside the array
    # ()

    #another example
    c = ( np.array([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]), 8 )
    print( c[0][0,2] ) # output: 3
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the help. I'm still a bit confused because when I try do this in a tuple like so `lists = [(c,'square')]` I get an invalid syntax error when trying to do `print(lists[0][0,2])`

Comment: which makes sense since I am accessing the first index (c,'square') but the [0,2] operator doesn't account for only the numpy array, it's looking at the tuple as a whole